# Azure Schema Registry client library python not working - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to use Schema Registry with Azure EventHubs following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/schemaregistry-readme?view=azure-python-preview). I can't make this guide work and it is not clear which endpoint for schema registry I should use. Can someone please help me with this?

info:

**script**

```py
import os
import sys
import logging
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventData
from azure.schemaregistry import SchemaRegistryClient
from azure.schemaregistry.serializer.avroserializer import SchemaRegistryAvroSerializer
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Create a logger for the SDK
logger = logging.getLogger('azure.schemaregistry')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Configure a console output
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)


os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID'] = "xxx"
os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'] = "xxx"
os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = "xxx"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

endpoint= "Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/"

schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(endpoint, credential, logging_enable=True, logger=logger)



schema_string = """
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}"""


schema_registry_client.register_schema("schema-test-group","schema-test-test","avro",schema_string)
```

**ERROR**

```
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CAE9D1CF70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

**LOG**

```
Request URL: 'https://Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/$schemagroups/schema-test-group/schemas/schema-test?api-version=REDACTED'
Request method: 'PUT'
Request headers:
    'X-Schema-Type': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    'Content-Length': '298'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': 'xxx'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azureschemaregistry/1.0.0b1 Python/3.9.2 (Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0)'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
A body is sent with the request
```

Comment: Have you tried using `xxx.servicebus.windows.net/` by itself?   The `Endpoint=sb://` is part of a connection string, but is not a valid URL that would resolve via DNS.

Comment: yes. I get `azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'`

Comment: That's progress.  An HTTP 400 (Bad Request) would indicate that your request body is malformed or invalid.  In this case, that likely indicates a problem with your schema itself.  Unfortunately, I can't speak to what a valid schema would look like outside of comparing with a known-good example.  You're setting an array for the `type`, which I'm not sure is valid.   For comparison:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/schemaregistry/Azure.Data.SchemaRegistry#register-a-schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the connection string should be in format `xxx.servicebus.windows.net`

the schema should look like

```py
"""{"namespace":"example.avro","type":"record","name":"User","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"favorite_number","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"favorite_color","type":["string","null"]}]}"""
```

(no \n and other characters)

check this github issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/18219